# Erro: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ola, qualquer script que executo, me retorna o seguinte erro.

```
 /bin/python3 "/home/Hofferman/Scripts Python/Untitled-1.py"                                                                     1 ↵
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Hofferman/Scripts Python/Untitled-1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib.request
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 86, in <module>
    import email
  File "/home/Hofferman/Scripts Python/email.py", line 3, in <module>
    import simplemail
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simplemail/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Poderia adicionar algum código à pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você criou um arquivo em `Scripts Python/email.py`, veja que o nome é `email.py`, isto **sobreescreve na execução** o pacote `email` nativo (somente para a execução atual).

Então ao invés da classe SMTP tentar procurar os módulos dentro de `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` ele vai tentar procurar dentro de `Scripts Python/email.py`, ou seja causando um conflito.

Para resolver isto basta dar um nome diferente para o seu arquivo `Scripts Python/email.py`, pode chama-lo de `Scripts Python/enviar-email.py`, ou então poderia mover script auxiliares para uma pasta como:

```
./Scripts Python
  ├───Untitled-1.py
  └───bibliotecas
      ├───email.py
      ├───foo.py
      └───bar.py
```

E importaria assim em seu script principal `Untitled-1.py`:

```
import bibliotecas.email
```

Ou se desejar apenas alguma função ou classe de dentro do `bibliotecas/email.py` faça:

```
from foo.email import <nome da função ou classe>
```

Troque `<nome da função ou classe>` pelo nome da função ou método que deseja usar que venha do seu script

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente isso que você respondeu.